# R plotly variable values tick distances to lower graph

Tags: r, plotly

I hope I explain it correctly but I have 2 graphs in 1 plot (so 2 y-axes). I would like to have y-axis2 lowered, so thats it not plotted in the whole plot (so I guess have variable values for the same tick distances). How is this possible?

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1:50,
                 y1 = c(20:5,6:10,9:3,4:20, 19:15),
                 y2 = c(100:115,200:204,50:44,4:20, 66:62))


plot_ly(df) %>% 
  add_lines(type = 'scatter', mode = "lines", 
            name = "test", 
            x = ~x, y = ~y1,
            line = list(color = '#999999'),
            hoverinfo = "text",
            text = ~paste(round(y1, 1), x))  %>%
  add_lines(type = 'scatter', mode = "lines", 
            name = "test", yaxis = 'y2',
            x = ~x, y = ~y2,
            line = list(color = '#CC79A7'),
            hoverinfo = "text",
            text = ~paste(round(y2, 1), x)) %>%
  #layout
  layout(title = "test",
         xaxis = list(titel = "Date", 
                      rangeslider = list(thickness = 0.05)),
         yaxis = list(side = 'left', title = 'test', 
                      showgrid = F, zeroline = F, type = "log",
                      showline = T),
         yaxis2 = list(side = 'right', overlaying = "y", 
                       title = 'test', 
                       showgrid = F, zeroline = F, 
                       showline = T))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can expand the axis with `range` and therefore lower the 200 position. And if you like to hide the values over 200, you may use `ticktext` and `tickvals` for showing just the values between 0 and 200.

```
plot_ly(df) %>% 
  add_lines(type = 'scatter', mode = "lines", 
            name = "test", 
            x = ~x, y = ~y1,
            line = list(color = '#999999'),
            hoverinfo = "text",
            text = ~paste(round(y1, 1), x))  %>%
  add_lines(type = 'scatter', mode = "lines", 
            name = "test", yaxis = 'y2',
            x = ~x, y = ~y2,
            line = list(color = '#CC79A7'),
            hoverinfo = "text",
            text = ~paste(round(y2, 1), x)) %>%
  #layout
  layout(title = "test",
         xaxis = list(titel = "Date", 
                      rangeslider = list(thickness = 0.05)),
         yaxis = list(side = 'left', title = 'test', 
                      showgrid = F, zeroline = F, type = "log",
                      showline = T),
         yaxis2 = list(side = 'right', overlaying = "y", 
                       title = 'test', 
                       showgrid = F, zeroline = F, 
                       showline = T, 
                       # added  code
                       range = list(0, 700),
                       tickvals = seq(0, 200, 50),
                       ticktext = seq(0, 200, 50)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thx! And is there a way to manually set the same tick distance with various values...for example have the lower values the same tick disctances/band (e.g. 1, 5,15 as the higher values(e.g. 50, 115, 200...like in a log scale...

Comment: I don't think you can specify it manually. But you may play around with the log function and find the log, that fits your case. ```type = "log", range = list(0, 4.5), dtick = "L5", tickvals = c(0,5,15,50,200), ticktext = c(0,5,15,50,200)```

Comment: Btw is there a way to have it reversed log? So if i have large spike in the lower values i.o. in the upper values?

Comment: do you possibly know reagrding my last comment?

Comment: Ehm how o you exactly mean? I dont see how the exponent variables will decrease the y-distance for lower values

Comment: A bit late answer but I still dont get what dtick ="L5" does...when I change this according to the explantation nothing happens...it seems that range = list(0, 4.5) is leading in this?